# VPAID issue with JWPlayer 6

Tags: jwplayer, ads, jwplayer6, vast, ova

I've tried unsuccessfully to integrate two separated VPAID test ad-tags.

The first one:

```
advertising: {
   "client": "vast",
   "tag": "http://search.spotxchange.com/vast/2.00/79391?VPAID=1&content_page_url=dzango.tv&cb=__random_number__&player_width=560&player_height=315&content_type=video"
}
```

The second one:

```
advertising: {
   "client": "vast",
   "tag": "http://app.scanscout.com/ssframework/get.xml?a=0&format=vast2.0&acceptVpaid=Y&vpaidType=direct&type=preroll&orgId=1&partnerId=61988&videoId=[VIDEO_ID]&videoTitle=[VIDEO_TITLE]&videoDesc=[VIDEO_DESCRIPTION]&videoPageUrl=[PAGE_URL]&videoUrl=dzango.tv&videoWidth=560&videoHeight=315&maxAdDuration=30&cacheBuster=__random-number__"
}
```

Can anyone help me please? I've tried the ad-tags on other pages/players (e.g. Google's Video Suite Inspector) successfully.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running these in the player?

Comment: Hi Ethan, I've created two test-pages for you. The first one: http://www.dzango.tv/test/1/test.html The second one: http://www.dzango.tv/test/2/test.html I've tried to publish my question in your forum. Unfortunately, it was identified as spam. Thanks :)

Comment: I used this demo-player-page to test the tags: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual

Comment: Hi, I can't watch these videos because this file does not work here in the US - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GW4kPIAQ2s, "The uploader has not made this video available in your country."

Comment: Hi Ethan, I've changed the video src to an available world wide movie. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use  "client": "googima", instead of  "client": "vast",

Comment: Great, no problem! :-)